# Summing columns in a data frame and adding those values to a new data frame in R

Tags: r

I am trying to sum the columns of a data frame and add these sums to a new output data frame.  When I run the following script, I get an error stating that the replacement has two rows and the data has 3.

```
a <-data.frame(replicate(3,sample(1:100,10,rep=TRUE)))
colnames(a) <- c("name1", "name2","name3")

for (i in 1:ncol(a)) {
 b <-as.data.frame(names(a))
 c <- sum(a[i])
 b$d[i] <- c[i]
}
```

I am looking for the output as a data frame such as:
name1 sum1
name2 sum2
name3 sum3

Comment: You could doe this with `colSums(a)`  In the loop, you may need `c <- sum(a[[i]])` and there is no `c[i]` as you are assigning one element to 'c'.  What is `d`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution was already pretty close. I made some slight modifications for you and it works:

```
a <-data.frame(replicate(3,sample(1:100,10,rep=TRUE)))
colnames(a) <- c("name1", "name2","name3")

b <-as.data.frame(names(a))

for (i in 1:ncol(a)) {
  b$sum[i] <- sum(a[i])
}
```

Output:

```
names(a) sum
1    name1 470
2    name2 616
3    name3 495
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a `dplyr` approach:

```
library(dplyr)
#Data
a <-data.frame(replicate(3,sample(1:100,10,rep=TRUE)))
colnames(a) <- c("name1", "name2","name3")
#Code
a %>%
  mutate(across(c(name1:name3),.fns = list(sum = ~ sum(.,na.rm=T)) ))
```

Output:

```
   name1 name2 name3 name1_sum name2_sum name3_sum
1     98    31    79       599       489       506
2      8    71     4       599       489       506
3     59    23    48       599       489       506
4     65    76    64       599       489       506
5     47    53    57       599       489       506
6     80    84    55       599       489       506
7     40    19    28       599       489       506
8     39     2    47       599       489       506
9     65    36    40       599       489       506
10    98    94    84       599       489       506
```

If only one dataframe is desired you can use this:

```
a %>%
  summarise(across(c(name1:name3),.fns = list(sum = ~ sum(.,na.rm=T)) ))
```

Output:

```
  name1_sum name2_sum name3_sum
1       599       489       506
```

Initial code should be used when you want to add those variables to same dataframe.

And if you want a variable for the names and another for results you can use previous code with `pivot_longer()` from `tidyverse` to produce this:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
a %>%
  summarise(across(c(name1:name3),.fns = list(sum = ~ sum(.,na.rm=T)) )) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything())
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  name      value
  <chr>     <int>
1 name1_sum   599
2 name2_sum   489
3 name3_sum   506
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be vectorized with `colSums` in `base R`

```
as.data.frame.list(colSums(a))
```

Or for a two column summary

```
stack(colSums(a))
```

If we need to create new columns in 'a'

```
a[paste0(names(a), "_sum")] <- colSums(a)
```